# Подсчет уникальных значений php

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица. Пример:

```
(country)
  RU 
  RU
  RU
  CE
  KL
  KL
  DE
```

Нужно, чтобы он вывел так:

```
RU - 3 
KL - 2 
CE - 1 
DE - 1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

p.s. кроме этих 4 значений, есть и другие разные.

Comment: про DISTINCT в SQL что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: ему не distinct нужно, тут group by нужно

Answer (score 4):

select country,count(country) from table group by country

Comment: бред, чем это поможет посчитать количество различных записей

Comment: тут название темы человек не правильно сформировал, судя по примеру ему не количество уникальных значений надо подсчитать. 
ему нужно подсчитать количество вхождений определенного значения в таблицу.
то что он привел в примере, легко решается группировкой

Comment: Как я понял, тут вывод нужно будет через цикл делать. Я в этом не очень, поможете?